# Верстка на html5

Tags: html, html5, css, вёрстка

Учусь верстать, сделана верстка макета на html5. Может, кто-нибудь согласится посмотреть верстку и высказать замечания? Если найдется кто-нибудь желающий, могу выслать архивом на мыло или в скайпе.

Comment: Заливай rghost.ru - и ссылку потом сюда.

Comment: http://rghost.ru/41156344

Comment: В целом неплохо. Но для такого простенького дизайна слишком много дивов. Можно облегчить код, за счет написания дополнительных правил в стилях.
Если тэг выполняет только одну функцию на странице то зачем ему лепить класс? Как например в случае H2? Если есть исключение где-нибудь, то его и прописать как класс.
Почему есть стили внутри тэгов на странице? Лень было или торопимся куда-то?

Comment: А какие дивы лишние, какие стоило бы убрать?  Стили внутри тегов есть только у картинок вроде.

Comment: [здесь все - все подробно][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Comment: большое всем спасибо за ответы, вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, наберите w3schools в гугле и почитайте вторую ссылку из результатов поиска.

Answer (score 6):

Ладно, сказал А буду молвить и Б :)

конструкция

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">
```

Если вынести элемент nav наружу, то див уже не нужен и можно прописать стили для тэга header

конструкция

```
<article>
    <div id="news-box">
```

тоже не нужен тут див. Далее в

```
<footer>
    <div id="copyright">
```

тоже див не нужен. Вставлять`<div style="clear: both;"></div>` в каждой свободной строчке пожалуй тоже не стоит. Уверен, их количество на странице можно значительно снизить.

```
<span class="company-name">COMPANY NAME</span>
<span class="slogan">short slogan goes here</span>
```

Здесь напрашивается какой-нибудь тэг из вида "H", span используется явно не по назначению.

BR - это тоже тэг и его тоже нужно закрывать. Таблица не используется для позиционирования объектов на странице. Таблица только для табличных данных.

Внутри IMG тэгов не прописывают высоту и ширину - есть стили для этого, если оригинальный размер должен быть изменен.

Хух, ну пока хватит.

Comment: @zhenyab, бр закрывать нужно в xhtml, но не в html.

Comment: >BR - это тоже тэг и его тоже нужно закрывать

И как его закрывают? так <br> </br> ??? 

Распространено только такое <br />

Comment: @Shrek, этот элемент является закрытым в соотвествии с xml-спецификацией

Comment: "Одинарные" элементы закрываются слэшем <img /> <br /> и т.д. Даже если <div /> написать в таком формате, то это будет равносильно <div></div> и не вижу тут места для сарказма.

Comment: @zhenyab, [читайте](http://december.com/html/4/element/br.html) "end tag: forbidden"

Comment: причем тут документация html 4 если мы про html5 тут говорим?

сам же писал

>@Shrek, значит в соответсвии с референсом. А не в перемешку 2 референса 4 и 5

уж не путай сам себя и окружающих.

Comment: Нет, нет! Товарисч stck совершенно прав. Мой предыдущий комментарий верен для XHTML, в HTML5 в отличие от HTML 4, <div /> будет прочитан как <div> и <br /> будет как <br>, а в HTML4 <br /> будет <br>&gt; и другие закрытые элементы соответственно также. Так что в HTML5 закрытие подобных тэгов совершенно опционально и не является запрещенным, как в HTML4.

Comment: большое всем спасибо за ответы, вы мне очень помогли)

Answer (score 2):

Ну теперь от убирания дивов ;) перейдём к убиранию аттрибутов.

```
<nav>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="About Us">About Us</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="Services">Services</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="Partners">Partners</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="Contact Us">Contact&nbsp;Us</a>
</nav>
```

Так писать правильно, но не корректно. Правильнее было бы идентифицировать ссылку не по её классу, а по родителю. По классам обычно идентифицируются элементы которые находятся врознь.

```
<nav id=menu>
    <a href="/" title="About Us">About Us</a>
    ...
</nav>
```

И стиль соответственно:

```
#menu > a{
.../*Ваш стиль .menu */
}
```

Если Вы начинаете что-то учить, с чего вы начнёте? Вот, и тут надо было начать с [референса](http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_HTML), потому как там Вам бы был предоставлен полный объём информации.

---

Идём далее. Никаких кавычек в аттрибутах.

```
<div class="news-date">12/01/2004</div>
```

Так делали Ваши деды. Нет нет и ещё раз нет. Первый шаг к дао:

```
<div class=news-date>12/01/2004</div>
```

Второй шаг к дао:

```
<time class=news_date>12/01/2004</time>
```

---

```
<img src="/images/photo2.jpg" title="Изображение" width="147" height="98">
```

Может стоило обойтись стилями? Чем писать размерность в каждой картинке?

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="titl">E-mail Addresses:</td>
        <td>veterimary@clinic.com<br>servise@clinic.com<br>support@clinic.com<br></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**...**

---

Вместо

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Используйте псевдо- *:after* и *:before* с указанным `clear`.

---

Comment: @stck, ну, с каквычками уж как-то совсем строго )) Утяжеляют страницу? Если целевой аудиторией будут те, у кого до сих пор dial-up - тогда да, это существенный аргумент. Но даже, если не брать это во внимание, то вот простейший пример:

    <!-- В "дедовском" варианте -->
    <span class="first second">text</span>
    <!-- В варианте продвинутых - это работать не будет -->
    <span class=first second>text</span>

Что в итоге? Каша, в которой есть часть с кавычками, часть без них. И т.к. я тот самый "дед", то читать такой код, мне не в кайф. В общем, не спешите выбрасывать кавычки на свалку ;

Comment: @Deonis, наличие нескольких значений через пробел в классе подразумевают под собой использование кавычек) Я и не выбрасывал - просто это соответсвует референсу, автор сказал что хочет девственный html5, я подумал что будет важным) Вы думаете мне в кайф? Я по своим нуждам вообще верстаю xhtml старенький стриктовый.
И да, утяжеляет. Я каноникализирую, так что каждый символ на счету:)

Comment: Соглашусь с @deonis что за бред? Что значит девственный html5?

Comment: @Shrek, значит в соответсвии с референсом. А не в перемешку 2 референса 4 и 5

Comment: большое всем спасибо за ответы, вы мне очень помогли)